# Snowflake SQL - Forward / Back fill a column with multiple values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to forward and back fill a column that has multiple values. My end result should be a filled column with duplicated values in the index.

My current dataset has a report month and a category. The category column could have a dynamic amount of category numbers with null values in between. There is 1 column for report month that is a distinct value.

| reportmonth | category |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | null |
| 2021-02 | 5 |
| 2021-03 | null |
| 2021-04 | null |
| 2021-05 | 10 |
| 2021-05 | 5 |
| 2021-06 | null |
| 2021-07 | null |

Here is the dataset that I am expecting:

| reportmonth | category |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 5 |
| 2021-01 | 10 |
| 2021-02 | 5 |
| 2021-02 | 10 |
| 2021-03 | 10 |
| 2021-03 | 5 |
| 2021-04 | 5 |
| 2021-04 | 10 |
| 2021-05 | 5 |
| 2021-05 | 10 |
| 2021-06 | 5 |
| 2021-06 | 10 |
| 2021-07 | 5 |
| 2021-07 | 10 |

I've tried using

```
first_value(category)  ignore nulls OVER (ORDER BY reportmonth ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED following) AS forward_fill
```

but this seems to stop once it hits the next category number. It also does not duplicate the report months.

There are other posts / questions similar to this, however none of them need to have the category repeat by the reportmonth.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, for each distinct value of category, you want to have rows of (reportmonth, category), is that correct?

Comment: Yes! That's correct  @ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *cross join* the distinct `reportmonth` values with the distinct `category` values, try the following:

```
Select R.reportmonth, C.category
FROM
(
  Select Distinct reportmonth 
  From yourTbl
) R
Cross Join
(
  Select Distinct category 
  From yourTbl Where category is not null
) C
Order By R.reportmonth
```

The output according to your sample data:

[image]